# Pointer to shift array C++

Tags: c++

Im trying to shift my array left as efficiently as possible. Im using pointers now, and im having trouble assigning the values back into my array:

```
void stack::rotate(int nRotations)
{
   if ( count <= 1 ) return;

   int *intFrontPtr = &items[top+1].n;
   int *intBackPtr  = &items[count-1].n;
   int temp = 0;

   for (int shift = 0; nRotations != 0 ;)
   {
        if ( nRotations > 0 ) // we rotate left
        {  
             temp = *++intFrontPtr; // give temp the value
             items[++shift].n = temp; // debug shows success
             if ( shift == count ) // dont overrun array
             {
                 temp = *intBackPtr;
                 items[count-1].n = temp;
                 shift = 0; // reset for another rotation
                 nRotations--; // decrement we have reached the end
             }
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: You'd probably get more help if you accepted answers more than just 21% of the time.

Comment: And also if he did not just repeated the same question over and over...

Comment: Too much is not given to answer this... For example, where is "top" defined... What is "n"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

c++ has a function built in in `<algorithm>`. Just call `std::rotate(front_ptr, front_ptr + N, back_ptr);`

Comment: referring to the items address might be the problem?